# How to draw line until middle point using quadraticBezierTo in flutter?

Tags: flutter, math

I'm trying to draw a line between three points using quadraticsBezierTo but here is my problem.

Current result:

[Current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrpzI.png)

Expected result:

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyTeD.png)

Code:

```
  final path = Path();
  path.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
  path.quadraticBezierTo(p2.x, p2.y, p3.x, p3.y);
  //Also tried: path.cubicTo(p2.x, p2.y, p2.x, p2.y, p3.x, p3.y);
```

Do you know how to achieved this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe,

```
path.quadraticBezierTo(
    2.0 * p2.x - 0.5 * (p1.x + p3.x), 2.0 * p2.y - 0.5 * (p1.y + p3.y), 
    p3.x, p3.y);
```

or

```
path.cubicTo(
    (4.0 * p2.x - p3.x) / 3.0, (4.0 * p2.y - p3.y) / 3.0, 
    (4.0 * p2.x - p1.x) / 3.0, (4.0 * p2.y - p1.y) / 3.0, 
    p3.x, p3.y);
```

#### Appendix

If you prefer sharper/blunter curves, throw away `quadratics Bezier curve` and take `cubic Bezier curve`. Then shift the control points evenly inwards/outwards.

```
double epsilon = -0.1;

path.cubicTo(
    (4.0 * p2.x - p3.x - epsilon * (p3.x - p1.x)) / 3.0, (4.0 * p2.y - p3.y - epsilon * (p3.y - p1.y)) / 3.0, 
    (4.0 * p2.x - p1.x + epsilon * (p3.x - p1.x)) / 3.0, (4.0 * p2.y - p1.y + epsilon * (p3.y - p1.y)) / 3.0, 
    p3.x, p3.y);
```

This breaks tangents at end points of the curve, though.

Comment: Looks like it works great for a quadraticBezierTo. How would you achieve the same result passing by 2 points using cubicTo?

Comment: Also which parameter should I change to make it looks a bit less rounded?

Answer (score 0):

Bezier curves aren't designed to pass through their control points, but if that's what you want you can do it by modifying the center point. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Constructing_B%C3%A9zier_curves)

> For quadratic Bézier curves one can construct intermediate points Q0 and Q1 such that as t varies from 0 to 1:
>
> - Point Q0(t) varies from P0 to P1 and describes a linear Bézier curve.
> - Point Q1(t) varies from P1 to P2 and describes a linear Bézier curve.
> - Point B(t) is interpolated linearly between Q0(t) to Q1(t) and describes a quadratic Bézier curve.

Thus,
`q0 = p0 * (1 - t) + p1 * t` and `q1 = p1 * (1 - t) + p2 * t` and the actual curve is

```
b = q0 * (1 - t) + q1 * t
  = p0 * (1 - t)^2 + p1 * t * (t - 1) + p1 * t * (t - 1) + p2 * t^2
  = p0 * (1 - t)^2 + 2 * p1 * t * (t - 1) + p2 * t^2
```

Note that by `^` I mean exponent, not xor.

So if you want your curve to pass through some point `c` at time `t = 1/2`, then we can find what `p1` should be.
`c = p0 * 0.25 + p1 * 0.5 + p2 * 0.25`
So,

```
p1 = 2 * c - 0.5 * (p0 + p2)
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew but if bezier curves aren't designed to pass through their control points, what should we use instead?

Comment: @MaxenceBourdin I mean you can use Bézier curves by modifying the control point in this way, I just find it a bit unnatural but if it makes sense for your application then go for it. One alternative is [polynomial interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) to construct the lowest degree polynomial that passes through all the provided points.